# Unexpected token , in JSON at position 10855 , NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, nodejs-server

I am fetching data from movieDB API in nodeJS using http.request method. While it works most of times, I am getting error if I reload the page(make API call) more than 10 or 15 times . Following is my code here -

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  let request = http.request(nowPlayingUrl, (response) => {
    // response is a readable stream
    let chunk = [];
    console.log(response.headers);
    response.on("data", (data) => {
      chunk.push(data);
    });
    response.on("end", () => {
      console.log("all data received");
      console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
    });
  });
  request.end();
  res.render("index.ejs");
});
```

and heres the error  -

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 10855
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>
```

there is also partial stringified data before app crashes with above mentioned error.

converting the chunk array to string and then parsing it to JSON doesnt produces any error -

```
`let d = JSON.stringify(chunk);
 console.log(JSON.parse(d));`
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `JSON.parse` on an array of strings, which tries to parse the comma-separated list of these strings. That is probably no valid JSON. Use `JSON.parse` on a string instead:

```js
let chunk = "";
response.on("data", (data) => {
  chunk += data.toString();
});
response.on("end", () => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
});
```

Of course this assumes that `nowPlayingUrl` does indeed return valid JSON.

`JSON.stringify` followed by `JSON.parse` just re-produces the array, but that's probably not what you want.